# How to make hotspot in Ubuntu?

Tags: wireless, internet, wireless-access-point, hot-spot

How to make wifi hotspot in Ubuntu?
I am having connected with wifi Internet and want to create wifi hotspot so that other devices gets connected with internet.

Comment: Last time I checked it was not possible to share a WiFi connection. Once you create your hotspot in managed mode, you loose your current WiFi connection. You need another Internet connection. See here: http://www.howtogeek.com/116409/how-to-turn-your-ubuntu-laptop-into-a-wireless-access-point/

Answer (score 2):

It is simple just click on your wifi icon and then create a new wifi network. 
Put name and password.

But it only works if your laptop is connect to a dongle or a wired connection.

Comment: You could have an ftp server, but you might need to be connected to an existing network.